In the book of Daniel 10:5-7 some say that this is a Christophany and in 10:10-15 is an Angel
In chapter ten of Daniel's book, we see Christophany with the angel messager. There is an appearance of Christ with an angel as a messenger who the prince of Persia delayed which the angel messenger needed Michael the Archangel's help 10:13. Or was this ׂa Christophany from 10:5 -21.?

The narrative in Dan 10 appears to involve at least two people:

the prophet Daniel (V1, 2, 7, 14, 12)
The vision of (V5, & 6) "a man dressed in linen, with a belt of fine gold from Uphaz around his waist. His body was like topaz, his face like lightning, his eyes like flaming torches, his arms and legs like the gleam of burnished bronze, and his voice like the sound of a multitude."  Note that is description is almost identical to that of Jesus found in Rev 1.  That is why this passage is called a "Christophany".
a third person whose identity is explored below.

In V9, this "Man dressed in linen" begins to speak. Note that the word "angel" does not occur anywhere in Dan 10.
Now, it has been debated whether "the one like a man" (V16, 18) who touched Daniel refers to:

"the man dressed in Linen" (V5, viz pre-incarnate Jesus), or,
someone else such as Gabriel who appeared to Daniel in Dan 8 & 9 whose name means, "man of God"

I am inclined to the latter view because this person (whoever it was) refers to someone greater than himself in V13, "Michael".  Now, without getting into a debate about the identity of Michael, this second transcendent person who touches Daniel that appears in V10 cannot be Jesus because Michael is greater than this messenger and no other being is greater than Jesus.
Therefore, I assume that the person appearing in V10 is not Jesus but a special messenger to Daniel, possibly Gabriel (as per Dan 8 & 9) but that is not stated.
